# Output of Binary classification using CNN

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, matconvnet

Hello I have recently started working on the CNN for the binary classification.

Here is my network:

```
net.meta.inputSize = [28 28 3] ;
net.meta.trainOpts.learningRate = 1e-02 ;
net.meta.trainOpts.numEpochs = 50 ;
net.meta.trainOpts.batchSize = 280 ;
opts.train.gpus = [];
f=1/100 ;
net.layers = {} ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv','weights', {{f*randn(5,5,3,50, 'single'), zeros(1, 50, 'single')}},'stride', 1,'pad', 0);
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'pool','method', 'max', 'pool', [2 2], 'stride', 2, 'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', 'weights', {{f*randn(5,5,50,30, 'single'),zeros(1,30,'single')}}, 'stride', 1, 'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'pool', 'method', 'max', 'pool', [2 2], 'stride', 2, 'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', 'weights', {{f*randn(4,4,30,50, 'single'),  zeros(1,50,'single')}}, 'stride', 1, 'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu') ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', 'weights', {{f*randn(1,1,50,2, 'single'), zeros(1,2,'single')}}, 'stride', 1, 'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1}= struct('type', 'dropout', 'rate', 0.9);
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'softmaxloss') ;
 net.meta.classes.name =arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%d',x),0:1,'UniformOutput',false);
disp( 'Net is Ok.' );

[net, info] = cnn_train( net, imdb, @getBatch, net.meta.trainOpts, opts.train, 'val', find( imdb.images.set == 2 ) ) ;
```

I am getting this output at the end if learning rate is `1e-2`
[image]

If reduce the learning significantly I am getting this output

[image]

Anyone please help me to tell which learning is good and what these graphs are showing?

**UPDATE:** 
I was doing slightly wrong. As the `cnn_train` function in MatConvNet is 'multiclass' by default so I have changed that to 'binary' Now I am getting this result with the combination of different learning rates `[0.00005*ones(1,10) 0.000005*ones(1,20) 0.0000005*ones(1,20)]`.
[image]

Comment: It is interesting to see your results. I guess it is clear that based on these figures your learning rate should be low so just run a test for different learning rate int he range between 1e-2 to 1e-8 and see which one give you the highest drop in loss with first iteration then with the chosen learning rate you can  later apply drop learning after few iteration or run again testing random search

Comment: @Feras I have updated the question. I want to know that in the last figure the 'brrerr' should be like that?

Comment: what is "brrerr" did you mean "binerr" this graph tells that your model overfitt your training data and there is no generalization. can you tell me the difference between the two model "binerr" and "objective"

Comment: Sorry it was "Binerr"  How can I avoid that over fitting? reducing the training samples as currently I am using 75% of 11816 for training? I am still trying to find difference between Binerr and Objective model

Comment: what are these two Binerr and Objective?

Comment: I am not sure about the Binerr but the Objective is the error of the transfer function

Comment: How do you post something you don't know what is it did you write the code of plotting what was the error you choose to plot ? what do u mean by transfer function and how can u plot a transfer ? I think you need to understand your project first then we can help u